# Creating new pandas columns from substrings in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have data in a csv called 'Features' which is of this form:

```
0      [Shops: Close by, Passing trade: Yes]
1      [Lift: Yes, No of Bedrooms: 1, Bedroom 1 Dims:...
2      [Lift: Yes, No of Bedrooms: 2, Bedroom 1 Dims:...
3      [No of Bedrooms: 4, Bedroom 1 Dims: 4.80 x 5.0...
4      [Finish: Excellent, Airconditioning: Yes, Shop...
...
```

and would like to create new pandas columns for the number of bedrooms.

```
0      [N/A]
1      [1]
2      [2]
3      [4]
4      [N/A]
...
```

I have tried something this like in python:

```
csvname['No of Bedrooms'] = [s for s in csvname['Features'] if 'No of Bedrooms' in s]
```

This did not work. Is there an easy way of doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `.str.extract`

```py
csvname['No of Bedrooms'] = csvname['Features'].astype(str).str.extract('No of Bedrooms: (\d+)')
```

```
print(csvname)

                                            Features No of Bedrooms
0              [Shops: Close by, Passing trade: Yes]            NaN
1  [Lift: Yes, No of Bedrooms: 1, Bedroom 1 Dims:...              1
2  [Lift: Yes, No of Bedrooms: 2, Bedroom 1 Dims:...              2
3  [No of Bedrooms: 4, Bedroom 1 Dims: 4.80 x 5.0...              4
4  [Finish: Excellent, Airconditioning: Yes, Shop...            NaN
```

Comment: I got a column with all values NaN.

Comment: @darzan Could you provide `df.head(10).to_dict()`?

Comment: I got something like: {0: ['Shops: Close by', 'Passing trade: Yes'],
 1: ['Lift: Yes',
  'No of Bedrooms: 1',
  'Bedroom 1 Dims: 10.00 x 10.00 mt',
  'No of Bathrooms: 1',
  'Dining Room Dims: 5.00 x 9.00 mt',
  'Kitchen Dims: 1.00 x 1.00 mt combined',
  'Living Room Dims: 1.00 x 1.00 mt combined',
  'Terrace (Front): Yes',
  'Has Views: Excellent Town views',
  'Type of View: Town views',
  'Finish: Very Good',
  'Shops: Within walking distance',
  'External Area: 5.00 sq mt',
  'Total Area: 64.00 sq mt'],...}

Comment: @darzan Updated the answer, remove the tailing `,`.